# Times zones and dates with PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I have a method that returns current dates for various days of the week:

```
        $dates = array_map(function ($value) {
            return (new \DateTime($value))->format('Y-m-d');
        }, ['tuesday', 'friday']);
```

This will output current dates for Tuesday and Friday:

0 => 2000-01-01
1 => 2000-01-04

The issue is, I need to get the dates from the perspective of a given time zone. i.e. someone sitting in New York, at 11pm on the Tuesday 1st will get current dates as:

0 => 2000-01-04
1 => 2000-01-08

Even though the 1st is still a valid date to them.

To resolve this, I have re-written the method like so:

```
        $days = array_map(function ($value) use ($config) {
            return (new \DateTime($value, new \DateTimeZone($config['user-timezone'])))->format('Y-m-d');
        }, ['tuesday', 'friday']);
```

As I am not sitting in NY, I have not actually tested this. I am interested in other solutions to this problem.

Comment: Your solution looks fine. What's the problem?

Comment: I will know by tomorrow - perhaps overthinking this.